# Large two column file for read.table in R, how to automatically ditch lines with the "line X did not have 2 elements"?

Tags: r

I have a large file consisting of two columns which I want to read in. While doing `read.table` I encounter this:

```
> x <- read.table('lindsay.csv')
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  line 493016 did not have 2 elements
```

Unfortunately that line is only 2% of the file..so finding all those lines which have a bit of corruption is really hard. Is there a way to `read.table` and automatically skip those lines which do not have 2 elements?

Comment: That line probably contains a `#` so R considers it a comment. Try changing the `na.strings` argument.

Comment: I would have thought that the `fill` argument would be more relevant (and then you'd have to drop those lines after the fact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, use read.csv() or use sep="," with read.table() if in fact you are working with a comma delimited value file.

```
x <- read.csv('lindsay.csv')
```

OR

```
x <- read.table('lindsay.csv', sep=",")
```

If that still doesn't work, you really should find out what is special about those lines and preprocess the text to fix them. This may mean either removing them, or correcting mistakes, or something else I haven't imagined.